# Fastapi problem with uploading image - file uploads only work with Swagger UI

Tags: jinja2, fastapi

I am having problem uploading image to my Fastapi endpoint using a File input component.

I have my backend endpoint as follows:

```
@router.post("/create", response_class=HTMLResponse)
@login_required
def job_create_post_view(
    request: Request, 
    db:Session=Depends(get_db),
    job_title: str=Form(default=None),
    job_image:Optional[UploadFile]=File(default=None)
    ):
```

And my jinja2 template with the file uploader input as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="/jobs/create" hx-post="/jobs/create">
        <div>
            <label for="job_image">Upload a photo </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="job_image" name="job_image" accept=".jpeg,.png,.jpg" placeholder="image" value="{%if job_image%} {{job_image}} {%endif%}">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2" type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

However, after I post the form, the value of the job_image is not picked up in my backend (returns a default None value). For example if I do a  print(job_image.filename) I get nothing.

Strangely when I post the form using Swagger UI at localhost:8000/docs it returns the job_image without any issues.

So it seems my input component in the Jinja2 template is faulty but I can't see anything wrong with it.

This must have something to do with Starlette as print(job_image) is giving me `<starlette.datastructures.UploadFile object>`

In my browser I am getting the following error:

```
 Response Status Error Code 422 from /jobs/create htmx.org@1.6.1:1
```

Comment: Can you compare the two requests in the browser console?

Comment: You have to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form if you want to post files, so `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...`

Comment: Yes I added enctype="multipart/form-data" but still the same problem. Uploading with Swagger UI always works but not from my html form

Comment: I figured out the problem. Its to do with the hx-post and I am supposed to add "multipart/form-data" to hx-encoding in the form.